# Windows Phone 8 - Pass an argument to callback function

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm fairly new to C# and developing for Windows Phone 8 and ran into a problem which I can't overcome.

I've created a class that does some HTTP request and at the end should invoke a callback function.

I need to pass an argument to the callback function, but i can't figure out how to do that.

It looks like I need IAsyncResult, but I can't create an instance of it.

I'm invoking the callback function using:

```
CallBack.Invoke(null);
```

Which works great, but I can't manage to pass an argument.

PS: `CallBack` is an AsyncCallback()

**Edit - More Code:**

Caller:

```
private void abcRenew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  api = new abcAPI();
  api.CallBack = new AsyncCallback(abcRenew_Click_callback);
  api.getNewAbc();
}

public void abcRenew_Click_callback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
  /* should get some values from api
}
```

API:

```
public class abcAPI
{
  public System.AsyncCallback CallBack { get; set; }

  public void getNewAbc()
  {
    call();
  }

  private void call()
  {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("...");
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(call_RequestStreamCallback), request);
  }

  void call_RequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
  {
    /* ... */
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(loadAndPostGeoposition_ResponseCallback), request);
  }

  void loadAndPostGeoposition_ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
  {
    /* ... */

    /* shall return this Pointer to CallBack function -> 
       Needs to be done, because there could be more than one running at the same time */
    if (CallBack != null)
      CallBack.Invoke(null);

  }
}
```

Comment: IAsyncResult is an interface, so you'd need to make an instance of something which implements it, but this doesn't look like something you should be manually calling.

Comment: Is it ok, to call `Invoke` then, or is there a better way?

Comment: Do you need to pass an argument value that is only known to the invoker of the callback or is it already known at creation time of the callback?

Comment: Only the invoker of the callback nows this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use anonymous methods like this:

```
private void abcRenew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var api = new abcAPI();

    Action<IAsyncResult> callback = asynchronousResult =>
    {
        /* Now `api` is in scope */
    };

    api.CallBack = new AsyncCallback(callback);
    api.getNewAbc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Use `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke` instead.

There is a full blown example of the exact same thing you need at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.asyncresult(v=vs.110).aspx . Notice how the return value is passed to the callback through `EndInvoke`. The compiler will generate the `AsyncResult` code automatically.

**edit**

After seeing more code it occurs to me that you are completly mistaken. It should be *really* easy to change the type of `abcApi.Callback` to `Action<YourReturnValueTypeHere>` and just invoke that instead. Adjust the argument type of the callback function accordingly and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you - But I'm not sure, if I can use this. - I try to invoke the callback function and give it some information (like in `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(...)`. - This way the Invoker would end up with the data of the callback function. - Or am I wrong?

Comment: @mrabe Please show more code. Both of the side providing the callback and of the side invoking it.

Comment: Ok, I've added more code. - Thank you sooo much for your help. - It is so frustrating to get stuck at such a (simple) problem. - I really appreciate your help.